# How to run nodejs project every hour on aws?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

So I have developed nodejs project for collect data from web and send to elasticsearch. I have problem about execute the project once per hour. How could i load my project to aws and execute once per hour?

Comment: Have you tried [AWS Lambdas](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda is the obvious choice.

Alternatively you can also run it in an EC2 instance with the proper CRON job configured.

Answer (score 1):

You should explore [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html).

In my experience I have found [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) to be really easy in achieving this.

Once you have setup the serverless, in `serverless.yml`, you can set the function to run every hour.

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0 */6 * * ? *)
```

In the above code, `hello` function would run every 6 hours.

Comment: Thankyou, I am very new in AWS, could you give me more detail about your solution. 1- my project is like crowler, am i deploy the project to amzon(which services) and trigger with lambda function?

Comment: Please read [serverless example for node](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/). Once you have a simple function running, change the config as I mentioned above and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Could use setInterval() function that nodejs provides. E.g: for executing a function once per hour you could use setInterval(yourFunction, 1000 * 60 * 60);

or cover the whole application in setInterval(function(//Here), 1000 * 60 * 60);